# Can't undo past last save, but only sometimes

Tags: undo-redo

I am editing a `*.tex` file.  I don't have persistent-undo set.  However, I can normally undo beyond my last save so long as I don't exit the file.  That's fine.

Sometimes, however, I am presented with the message "Already at oldest change".  That's quite a downer.  Why does this happen *sometimes*?

My Vim version is below.  It includes persistent-undo, but it shouldn't matter in the context of this question.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 12 2021 19:50:09)
Included patches: 1-3755
Modified by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
Compiled by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
   <...snip...> +persistent_undo <...snip...>
```

Comment: The oldest change (without setting `undofile`) is going to be the state of the buffer at the time it was loaded. So if I do `vim file`, `ochange<esc>:write<cr>`, I can still `u` past that `:write` (most recent save). But if I understand your question, you say sometimes this doesn't work? Maybe check `undolevels`. Also `:help :undolist` and related commands/sections.

Comment: Thanks, D. Ben Knoble.  I don't think it's `undolevels` because it's only a few actions back in time.  As for `undolist`, I will try that the next time I see the problem (which is not frequent).  At this instant, I've made far too many changes to the `*.tex` file.

Comment: Well, it happened again.  The `:undolist` command didn't show much.  Two unspecified changes a few minutes back. It doesn't matter whether I repeat `Ctrl+R` until I run out of redo's or repeat `u` until I run out of undo's.  Nothing visibly changes in the file when I do either of those, and `:undolist` shows the same two changes in both cases.

Comment: Huh. What is `:verbose set undolevels?` (before and after it happens)? Is `autoread` set?

Comment: I'll look at those when I re-encounter the problem, then post back.  Thanks.